# Why is blue circle not spinning in the center of itself

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

Why is the blue circle not rotating in the center of its own axis?
Below you can find my previous code.

Here you can see my **CSS** with the proportionate **SVG**:

```css
circle {
  animation: grow 2s infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="80"
     height="110"
     version="1.1">
     <rect width="70"
           height="100"
           x="5"
           y="5"
           fill="white"
           stroke="red"
           stroke-width="10"
           rx="5"/>
     <circle cx="40" cy="105" r="3" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [transform-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box): fill-box;

```css
circle {
  animation: grow 2s infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="80"
  height="110"
  version="1.1"
>
  <rect
    width="70"
    height="100"
    x="5"
    y="5"
    fill="white"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="10"
    rx="5"
  />
  <circle cx="40" cy="105" r="3" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because scale in SVG is different, it makes scale in X & Y axis. Additionally it scales "cx" and "cy" properties.
The best way is to make "cx" & "cy" at 0 and use the "translate" to coordinates you need

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="110" version="1.1">
      <rect
        width="70"
        height="100"
        x="5"
        y="5"
        fill="white"
        stroke="red"
        stroke-width="10"
        rx="5" />
     <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="3" fill="blue" transform="translate(40 105)">
      <animateTransform 
                     attributeName="transform"
         type="scale" 
         additive="sum" 
         from="1 1" 
         to="1 1" 
         values="1 1; 0.5 0.5; 1 1" 
         begin="0s" 
         dur="2s" 
         repeatCount="indefinite">
       
      </animateTransform>
     </circle> 
    </svg>
```

Enjoy!